# Binary Human Readable to Real Size

Tags: javascript, byte, filesize

I'd like to convert human readable size (for example "10Mi") back to a real number size

I wrote the following but I seem to be missing something in the conversion

```js
function humanFileSizeToSize (sizeString) {
    const units = ['Ki', 'Mi', 'Gi', 'Ti', 'Pi', 'Ei', 'Zi', 'Yi'];
    const unitString = units.find(unit => sizeString.includes(unit));
    const power = units.indexOf(unitString) + 1;
    const size = parseFloat(sizeString.slice(0, sizeString.indexOf(unitString)))
    return parseInt(size * (1024**power));
}

console.log(humanFileSizeToSize("10Mi"))
console.log(humanFileSizeToSize("1.5Mi"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work as expected assuming 1 MiB is equal to 1048576 bytes.

Can be shortened though, and done without a library

```js
const units = [, 'Ki', 'Mi', 'Gi', 'Ti', 'Pi', 'Ei', 'Zi', 'Yi'];
const re = /(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([KMGTPEZYi]{2})/g;
const humanFileSizeToSize = sizeString => {
  const [[_,size,unit]] = sizeString.matchAll(re);
  const power = units.indexOf(unit)
  return parseInt(size * (1024 ** power));
}

console.log(humanFileSizeToSize("1Ki"))
console.log(humanFileSizeToSize("1Mi"))
console.log(humanFileSizeToSize("1.5Mi"))
console.log(humanFileSizeToSize("10Mi"))
console.log(humanFileSizeToSize("1Gi"))
```

Comment: The regex won't work with floats though (`1.4Gi`)